# Access-Control-Allow-Methods doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have a small Web API app up on a web server, with one GET method that returns 3 records, and a POST method that accepts an object and then assigns it an ID and returns the same object.

I'm making ajax calls from a local web app, and testing out my CORS implementation. Almost everything so far, is working well. If I don't specify an Access-Control-Allow-Origin (just set to `*` for now), my calls are disallowed (what I expect), but I also tried specifying Access-Control-Allow-Methods and it doesn't seem like my input restricts specific calls from being made.

For example, this is what my web.config contains:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With " />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS, GET" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I only have `OPTIONS` and `GET` listed, but I am still able to make POST requests. Likewise, if I set it it `"OPTIONS, POST"` I am still able to make GET requests.

**EDIT**

Based on the answer from @geekonaut below I was able to see this function as I'd expect. I attempted to try a `PUT` request, rather than `GET` or `POST`, but then I got an error that the `OPTIONS` (preflight) request wasn't allowed. I first needed to add a section in my `Global.asax.cs` file to accept that method, then if I toggled adding/removing `PUT` in my web.config's `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` value, I saw that it would only allow that method if it was listed.

```
protected void Application_OnBeginRequest()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any useful information from the preflight request or the headers after any request?

Comment: Anything specific I should be looking for? I see that is attempting a POST request, and that the Access-Control-Allow-Methods value is `OPTIONS, GET` so it seems that everything is set correctly in the pre-flight.

Comment: I am not really into asp.net, but did you try something like the configuration mentionned in the **filter by verbs** section here [https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering](https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering), I'm starting to think that maybe the server sends the headers only, with no real verification of the client request.

Comment: Thanks for the response @JordanQuagliatini but it turns out the issue had to do with my misunderstanding of the type of methods that can be restricted by that property, as well as allowing a 200 response from `OPTIONS` requests - I've updated my post above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CORS does not prevent a simple (or even preflighted) `POST` request based on its method.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` will only be effective for requests that could not have been made with a simple cross-origin form, for instance.

That means: `GET` and `POST` can skip the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` as described in [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/):

> Simple cross-origin requests generated outside this specification
>   (such as cross-origin form submissions using **GET or POST** or
>   cross-origin GET requests resulting from script elements) typically
>   include user credentials, so resources conforming to this
>   specification must always be prepared to expect simple cross-origin
>   requests with credentials.
>
> Because of this, resources for which simple requests have significance
>   other than retrieval must protect themselves from Cross-Site Request
>   Forgery (CSRF) by requiring the inclusion of an unguessable token in
>   the explicitly provided content of the request.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense, I hadn't seen that part in the documentation before apparently. I'll modify my question above to show how I was able to see the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` property function more like I'd expect.

Comment: but if the POST request isn't simple (suppose we set some headers in request) then I found Access-Control-Allow-Methods still ignore it regardless preflight request is send before the real POST request.

Comment: @QuocVanTang Yes POST still need not be required to be present in `access-Control-Allow-Methods` but the non simple headers needs to be present in response header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. Non simple headers due to which a simple POSt request became non simple POST request will be validated and taken seriously by cors enabled server.